# Persisted sign in with Firebase Javascript SDK

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase npm package (version 5.2.0) for client side authentication and database.

For some reason even when I set persistence to **LOCAL**, each refresh **the current user is null**.

Signing in:

```
export const login = (email, password) => {
    return firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
        .then(() => {
            return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
        })
}
```

Getting current user:

```
export const currentUser = () => {
     return firebase.auth().currentUser;
}
```

Another oddity is when I apply database rules while using persistence. I get a permission error. The error disappears if the rules are set to public read/write. Does the persistence mechanism need access to the database?

[image: Firebase error]

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

Instead of fetching logged in user by `firebase.auth().currentUser`.

Here is the note in firebase docs for using `firebase.auth().currentUser`

> Note: currentUser might also be null because the auth object has not finished initializing. If you use an observer to keep track of the user's sign-in status, you don't need to handle this case.

Reference: [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed_in_user)